# Can TensorFlow work with JSON like data?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Suppose we have a JSON record like:

```
{
   "Name" : "Tom",
   "Diseases" : [{
          "Asthma" : [{
                        "Severity":5
                        "Medication" : [{
                                         "Benzene" : [{
                                                       "Start Date" : 10-5-2017,
                                                       "End Date" : 22-5-2018
                                                      }]
                                       }]
                     }]
                 }]
}
```

which has a lot of interdependent features, Is there a way we could input this into a TensorFlow Deep neural network??

Answer (score 3):

More or less, but not directly. There is an API to feed JSON data, but this must be a [JSON mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) of a [`tf.train.Example` protocol buffers object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto). However these objects cannot hold hierarchical data like what you show, only collections of [features](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto) corresponding to either integers, floats or bytes. In your case, you could be something like this:

```
{
  "features": {
    "feature": {
       "Name": { "bytes_list": { value: ["VG9t"] } },
       "Disease": { "bytes_list": { value: ["QXN0aG1h"] } },
       "Severity": { "int64_list": { value: [5] } },
       "Medication": { "bytes_list": { value: ["QmVuemVuZQ=="] } }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that strings must be given as arrays of bytes, which need to be encoded in Base64 in the JSON format of protocol buffers. However, this does not allow for records with multiple diseases, since, as I said, it does not support hierarchical structure.

You could have one record per patient and disease instead, for example. If you actually get to the point where you have that JSON document as input, you would use [`tf.decode_json_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_json_example) to obtain the protocol buffer binary representations of the objects, and then [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) to actually obtain the tensors.

Comment: Thank you :)
What would be the best way to input a very complex JSON object with multiple diseases, multiple medications, etc..into Tensorflow?

Comment: @RakshithYashvanth Well, that very much depends on what you intend to do with the data. I mean you can have complex structures for example with multiple tensors related by "key" values, database-style, but that is hardly useful as it is if you want to do machine learning. One possibility is to repeat records, one per disease, but then you lose comorbility information. Another typical option are sparse encodings, you have one "column" per disease and medication with 1/0 values indicating presence or not (although I'm not sure how you'd encode disease severity...).

Comment: I was looking at ways to input the whole patient record as an input to a deep neural network so that the co-morbidness and other inter-data relationships are preserved

Comment: @RakshithYashvanth Well then you can use a sparse encoding like I said. I'm thinking, you could have a number (instead of just a 1/0) value per possible disease, with 0 meaning "doesn't have it" and anything else the severity. For medications, you could keep just 1/0 or also use a number indicating the (relative) amount of medication used by the patient, if you have that information. In any case, it is preferred that you normalize your values to a common range (e.g. [0, 1]) so every factor has similar base weight.

Comment: @RakshithYashvanth Ah, and I forgot about the dates. It's complicated to encode that kind of temporal information along with non-temporal data, more so if you have many possible medications (and maybe even multiple periods per medication?). If you want, you can think of how to reshape your data as some kind of time series, and then use something like a recurrent model, that is better for temporal dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2021:**

There now seems to be experimental support with [tfio.experimental.serialization.decode_json](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/serialization/decode_json) but not much documentation yet.

You can read some more in the [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/pull/695) or the [unit tests](https://github.com/djl11/io/blob/44e0c9e116c681d0479ea2f5efde290d2c956ba1/tests/test_serialization_eager.py#L191-L226)

Example code:

```py
import tensorflow_io as tfio

json_text = r'{"test":["this","is","some","data"],"bar":42,"baz":[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]}'

specs = {
    "test": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([4]), tf.string),
    "bar": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([]), tf.int32),
    "baz": tf.TensorSpec(tf.TensorShape([4,2]), tf.int32),
}
parsed = tfio.experimental.serialization.decode_json(json_text, specs)

print(parsed)
```

outputs:

```
{
    'test': <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'this', b'is', b'some', b'data'], dtype=object)>, 
    'bar': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=42>, 
    'baz': <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
    array([[1, 2],
           [2, 3],
           [3, 4],
           [4, 5]], dtype=int32)>
}
```